# Debugging undefined method error in rake script

Tags: ruby, rake

When running a local rake script that uses some ruby gems including configatron I get the following error. Can anyone suggest a good way to debug this as it seems that the ability to debug scripts like this is very not particularly intuitive.

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `path_to_command=' for #<MSBuild:0x2bed440>
D:/_src/******/buildscripts/******/rakefile.rb:65:in `block (2
levels) in <top (required)>'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/albacore-0.2.5/lib/albacore/support/createta
sk.rb:18:in `call'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/albacore-0.2.5/lib/albacore/support/createta
sk.rb:18:in `block in msbuild'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `call'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `block in execute'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `each'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `execute'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:595:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:605:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:602:in `each'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:602:in `invoke_prerequisites'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:594:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:605:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:602:in `each'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:602:in `invoke_prerequisites'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:594:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:581:in `invoke'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2041:in `invoke_task'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `each'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `block in top_level'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2013:in `top_level'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1992:in `run'
D:/Ruby192/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
```

Many Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Hi could you post the output of "gem list --local" here. Also paste/attach your rake file if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling it could be related to this bug-report mentioned on the albacore github.

https://github.com/derickbailey/Albacore/issues/63

Comment: spot on, it looks like the script has been written to work in an older version of albacore, I modify the script and it continues further.